# How do I complete the exampleExternalContract in eth-scaffold tutorial 1?

Tags: solidity, tutorials

I am following the tutorials in eth-scaffold and I'm on Chapter 1.

https://github.com/austintgriffith/scaffold-eth/tree/challenge-1-decentralized-staking --> link to the tutorial

I get this error, when I try and execute the example contract (this tutorial builds a decentralized staking smart contract).

```
eth_sendRawTransaction
  Contract call:       <UnrecognizedContract>
  Transaction:         0x6c9c91bf6e2bacd32eb560b2e1922aacec848dd0dd0d6011d695ee639d57a39c
  From:                0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266
  To:                  0x5f3f1dbd7b74c6b46e8c44f98792a1daf8d69154
  Value:               0.5 ETH
  Gas used:            43626 of 43653
  Block #55:           0x616fa7063736af541020d99e3f6d6debad67b694c958565d85f7b958859dff97

  Error: Transaction reverted without a reason
      at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0x1291be112d480055dafd8a610b7d1e203891c274)
      at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0x5f3f1dbd7b74c6b46e8c44f98792a1daf8d69154)
      at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

I didn't think I was doing anything revolutionary -

```
function stake() public payable {
    balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    if (address(this).balance > threshold && block.timestamp <= deadline) {
        exampleExternalContract.complete{value: address(this).balance}();
    }
    emit Stake(msg.sender, msg.value);
}
```

This is the provided example contract

```
pragma solidity 0.8.0;

contract ExampleExternalContract {
    bool public completed;

    function complete() public payable {
        completed = true;
    }
}
```

I know that the "if" statement is getting triggered and it's erroring before it hits the emit Stake because I see two Stake events in the UI.

What's a good way to debug this as the error message is pretty unhelpful?

Comment: The code seems fine, no obvious mistake: called function is payable, doesn't have a require, nor array involved that causes access out of bounds. From the error message the only odd thing is `Gas used: 43626 of 43653`, it seems the transaction has run out of gas. To debug test contract I use remix, for contract in public testnet etherscan provides a transaction trace that helps sometimes.